# Unable to show cart data base on category (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have these Three models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    photo= models.ImageField(upload_to = 'image/', default = 'None/no-img.jpg')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Category has data of

```
-------
name
-------
1 Clothing
2 Electronics
3 Phones
4 Books
5 Home decors
------------

class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    local_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    scientific_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    c_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='c_id_typtype', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    short_details = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Item has data of type

```
-------
item_name          category(fk)
-------
1. Levies jeans       1(Clothing)
2. UCB T-shirts       1(Clothing)   
3. Samsung M10 Phone  3(Phones)   
4. ASUS T123 Phone    3(Phones)
...
...
------------

class DisplayCart(models.Model):
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='cart_item',blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='cart_cat',blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='cart_user_id',blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    cart_item_updated_date = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.item_id.item_name
```

DisplayCart has data of type with user_id of this

```
 -----------------------------------
    item_id         category_id qty   user_id
    -----------------------------------
    1(Levies jeans)     1       2   32
    2(Samsung M10)      3       1   32
    ...
    ...
    ----------------------------------
```

This is my View part

```
def showcart(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    items = Item.objects.all()
    loginuser = request.user.id
    cart_items = DisplayCart.objects.all().filter(user_id=loginuser)
    print("C users ...."+ str(cart_items))
    context = {"home": "active", "categories":categories,  "items":items, "cart_items":cart_items}
    
    return render(request,'cart_checkout/cart.html', context)
```

i am trying to show Cart (user_id of 32) base on category format in template like this

```
-------------------
Clothing    qty
-------------------
Levis Jeans     2

-------------------
Phones        qty
-------------------
Samsung m10    1
```

But it is showing like this (want to remove other categories)

```
-------------------
Clothing    qty
-------------------
Levis Jeans     2

-------------------
Electronics qty
-------------------
-------------------
Phones        qty
-------------------
Samsung m10    1

-------------------
Books         qty
-------------------
Home decors    qty
-------------------
```

This is my Template view of cart.html

```
 {% for cat in categories %}
                    
                    <h3>{{cat.name}}</h3>  
            {% for cartdata in cart_items %}
                         
                    {% if cat.id == cartdata.categories.id %}
            <ul>
                <li>{{cartdata.items.item_name}}</li>
                <li>{{cartdata.quantity}}</li>
            </ul>
            ...
             {% endif %}

                     {% endfor %}   

 {% endfor %}
```

i have tried many logic and check related question but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the categories to show only ones which has display items. For example:

```
def showcart(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    loginuser = request.user.id
    cart_items = DisplayCart.objects.all().filter(user_id=loginuser)
    categories = Category.objects.filter(pk__in=cart_items.values_list('category_id_id', flat=True))
```